# login into same page while rounting | angular

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TodosComponent } from '../todos/todos.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  enterUserName='';
  enterPassword='';
  isLogin= false;

  onCheckCredentail(userName: HTMLInputElement, password: HTMLInputElement) {
    if (userName.value==='Balveer' && password.value==='Balveer123' ) {
      this.isLogin=true;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/todos');
    } else {
      this.enterUserName="incorect password and username "
      this.isLogin=false;
    }
  }
}
```

answer to this quesstion if any body knows. that will grateful. im doing it from pst 2 week but not able to find the solution

Comment: What is the question ? Can you explain the behavior you are expecting, and the behavior you are witnessing ?